# Discord.js restore a guild icon in guildUpdate event

Tags: node.js, file, discord.js

I am currently making a Discord bot (v14.11), and the purpose of the bot is to fully secure the server, so it is supposed to cancel any action performed by someone who hasn't the rights to do it. The system is working on the roles so far, and now I'm trying to do the same for the server.

The problem is that to update the icon, it is either a file or a local file path, and the API only provides the API link to the icon.

I tried to use axios to download the file, restore the old icon, and then delete it (locally), but the API doesn't provide the .webp format, which is useful if the icon is animated. It is also possible to try to send two requests, a first one requesting a gif format, and in case of fail, requesting a png format. Once again, a new problem occurs: the API often replies by a 404 error, the file doesn't exist (probably because it hasn't been uploaded yet)

```
const download = async() => {
    const gif = await axios.get(`https://cdn.discordapp.com/icons/${before.id}/${before.icon}.gif`, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' }).catch(() => {});
    if (!gif) {
        const png = await axios.get(`https://cdn.discordapp.com/icons/${before.id}/${before.icon}.png`, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' }).catch(() => {})
        if (!png) return false;

        fs.writeFileSync(`./dist/data/${before.id}-icon.png`, Buffer.from(png.data), 'binary')
        return '.png'
    }
    fs.writeFileSync(`./dist/data/${before.id}-icon.gif`, Buffer.from(gif.data), 'binary')
    return '.gif';
}

const downloaded = await download();
if (!!downloaded) {
    await after.setIcon(`./dist/data/${before.id}${downloaded}`).catch(() => {})
    fs.rmSync(`./dist/data/${before.id}${downloaded}`)
}
```

That small part of code is the closest I can get to the goal I'm aiming at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually pass a cdn link (or other links to files) to `<Guild>.setIcon();`.

Additionally, you can also get the icon url in a webp format with `<Guild>.iconURL()`. You may want to pass `{size: 4096}` to get the best possible resolution discord may want to provide to you.

Relevant Docs:

- https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/Guild?scrollTo=iconURL
- https://discord.js.org/docs/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/Guild?scrollTo=setIcon

According to your snippet (and assuming that `before` and after contain Guild classes), an example of code would be:

```js
const iconurl = before.iconURL({ size: 4096 });
await after.setIcon(iconurl);
```

Mind that you can also override the file extension by passing the `extension` property in addition to the size parameter.

Comment: Oh yeah it works, you're right. I tought I tried it, I guess I forgot to compile the code before run, thanks ^^